# Purpose of solid plane on flex in wireless earbuds

Tags: wireless, flex

I'm looking at a teardown of Sennheiser Momentum wireless earbuds. It is a rigid-flex design that folds into the casing:
￼[image: sennheiser1]

My question is about the flex that sticks out to the right in the picture above. Here is another picture with the part I’m wondering about circled in red:
￼[image: sennheiser2]

When folded into the casing it would end up facing out toward the plastic.

The Earin M-2 wireless earbuds also have something similar:
￼[image: earin]

What is it and what does it do?

Comment: Maybe it's an antenna?

Comment: Antenna is my guess too, given that it seems to have a 'guard trace' in the form of a ground plane around the trace leading to it.

Comment: I was thinking it could be a proximity sensor? To sense if it is inserted into an ear. Not the actual volume etc touch controls, just proximity

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pad for capacitive touch sensing. This could be used in a wireless earbud for sensing if the earbuds are in your ear or for sensing finger taps for actions like pausing music.

A monitoring device like a microcontroller will charge the pad and measure the time it takes for the voltage to decay, which is a function of the capacity. The capacitance of the pad will change when a finger is nearby

[image: Capacitive touch sensing illustration]
Image source: https://www.embedded.com/waking-up-a-capacitive-touch-sensing-device-with-an-mcu-peripheral/

You can see a tutorial about some capacitive touch sensor modules here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-capacitive-touch-sensor-breakouts

Comment: That’s the correct answer!